# Fetch values from foreach

Tags: php

I have an array

```
$selectName = [''BX_NAME0''];

var_dump($selectName);
```

outputs:-

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'BX_NAME0' (length=8)
```

But $_POST["BX_NAME0"] also has value and i want to pick that value from $selectName array .
But when I write

```
foreach($selectName as $sn){
    echo $_POST['"'.$sn.'"']; 
}
```

It gives error  `Undefined index: "BX_NAME0"` 
BUT

`echo $_POST["BX_NAME0"];` gives the values.

I want values to fetched from foreach loop.

Comment: There is a difference between `''BX_NAME0''` and `'BX_NAME0'` or `"BX_NAME0"`... You are trying to access `$_POST["'BX_NAME0'"]` which indeed does _not_ exist.

Comment: Actually sorry, you are trying to access `$_POST['"BX_NAME0"']`, but that one does not exist too.

Comment: Assuming that those doubled quote chars (`''`) in your first code block are a typo here on SO (since that is a clear syntax error) it looks like you simply have to access `$_POST[$n]` and all is fine.

Comment: @arkascha it worked echo $_POST[$sn]; simply like this ......thanx 4 the solution ...you can make it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: It was @Bhavika who gave the answer below. Though as mentioned in the comments to that answer it still can be improved by removing the quote chars around the variable to `echo $_POST[$sn];`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this I hope it's useful for you 
In for each

```
echo $_POST[$sn];
```

Comment: Those quote characters do not make any sense at all in this. One can simply leave them away without any effect. Please read about how strings are built in PHP.

Comment: Then use it without any type of quote

Comment: If you change your answer that way then this might actually be the correct solution, though the question is vague and other issues might exist.